# when i send more then 1 header it returns 400 error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, discord

```
$url = 'https://discord.com/api/guilds/******323098841117/members/'.$_SESSION['cid'];
$data = array("access_token" => 'Bearer '.$_SESSION['token']);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
$arr = ['Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bot NzI2NTQ5NjI1MDYx**********xBakg.ZfpEdgqsW3rZuPLTXSm5Q5p20bU'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arr);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo($response);
echo("Bearer ".$_SESSION['token']);
echo("Welcome back, ".$_SESSION['name']);
```

400 error

in headers bot token

bot is already on server

Comment: You tell to send JSON, but you don't.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now working!

Comment: I've posted a detailed answer, for other people may having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the header itself. The content-type sent is `application/json`, but the data transmitted via cURL is not JSON, but a URL encoded key/value pair.

`$data` is an array like set here

```
$data = array("access_token" => 'Bearer '.$_SESSION['token']);
```

and you correctly transform it to text

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

But it has to be converted to JSON, so just replace `http_build_query` with `json_encode` like below.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```